# how to convert BeanFactory to ApplicationContext

Tags: spring

I have some code like this:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class MyBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor, PriorityOrdered {
    

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory) throws BeansException {


        ListableBeanFactory listableBeanFactory  = factory;
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = (ApplicationContext) listableBeanFactory;
        AbstractApplicationContext context = (AbstractApplicationContext) applicationContext;
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = context.getEnvironment();
        AbstractEnvironment abstractEnvironment = (AbstractEnvironment) environment;
        abstractEnvironment.getProperty("business.bean.dependsOn");

       // how to gain ApplicationContext
       //.........
}
```

I want to obtain some config value  from classpath:application.properties
and only ApplicationContext could getEnvironment.
how to gain ApplicationContext?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on: 1. Are you using Spring boot or spring and (you haven't listed spring boot in a tag, but using application.properties file which probably implies spring boot) 2. What exactly would you like to achieve? Loading certain beans depending on values in the application properties?

Comment: Don't make your `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` an `@Component` it needs to be declared as a `static` `@Bean` method. To get the environment implement the `EnvironmentAware` interface to get access.

Answer (score 0):

The ApplicationContext object can be obtained by implementing the ApplicationContextAware interface.

The Value annotation gets the attributes in application.properties.

Comment: 1. “implementing the ApplicationContextAware interface”， but the Aware invoked at Bean Initialization,  which is after  invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessor(in spring fresh).   so at the time MyBeanFactoryPostProcessor#postProcessBeanFactory invoked, Aware has't call.

Comment: Don't know how do you want to use, but the call MyBeanFactoryPostProcessor. PostProcessBeanFactory before,Will instantiate and initialize MyBeanFactoryPostProcessor first.

If realized in MyBeanFactoryPostProcessor ApplicationContextAware interface, can satisfy your requirements?